# ComboBox MeasureItem Event Not firing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to develop a custom combobox (which is in a toolstrip) in which items are 5 font styles that I would display as they look.

Problem: I can't set the size of each item. The *MeasureItem* event doesn't fire and I can't find out why.

So it looks like this:
[image]

Not far but not quite my tempo! ^^

Here's my code:

```
Public CorpusFontStyleTitre1 As Font = New Font(New FontFamily("Lato"), 18, FontStyle.Bold, 3)
Public CorpusFontStyleTitre2 As Font = New Font(New FontFamily("Lato"), 16, FontStyle.Underline Or FontStyle.Bold, 3)
Public CorpusFontStyleTitre3 As Font = New Font(New FontFamily("Lato"), 14, FontStyle.Underline Or FontStyle.Bold, 3)
Public CorpusFontStyleTitre4 As Font = New Font(New FontFamily("Lato"), 12, FontStyle.Underline, 3)
Public CorpusFontStyleCorpsdeTexte As Font = New Font(New FontFamily("Lato"), 12, FontStyle.Regular, 3)

Public Structure CorpusFontStyleItem
        Dim strTextStyleName As String
        Dim fontTextStyle As Font
        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return strTextStyleName
        End Function
End Structure

Private Sub frmCorpusManagement_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadcmbFontStyle()
        cmbFontStyle.ComboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        AddHandler cmbFontStyle.ComboBox.DrawItem, AddressOf cmbFontStyle_DrawItem
        AddHandler cmbFontStyle.ComboBox.MeasureItem, AddressOf cmbFontStyle_MeasureItem
End Sub

Private Sub cmbFontStyle_MeasureItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MeasureItemEventArgs)
        Select Case e.Index
            Case "1"
                e.ItemHeight = 50
            Case "2"
                e.ItemHeight = 40
            Case "3"
                e.ItemHeight = 30
            Case "4"
                e.ItemHeight = 20
            Case "5"
                e.ItemHeight = 10
        End Select

End Sub

Private Sub cmbFontStyle_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawItemEventArgs)
        e.DrawBackground()
        Dim myItem As CorpusFontStyleItem = DirectCast(cmbFontStyle.Items(e.Index), CorpusFontStyleItem)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(myItem.strTextStyleName, myItem.fontTextStyle, New SolidBrush(Color.Black), e.Bounds)
        e.DrawFocusRectangle()
End Sub  

Private Sub LoadcmbFontStyle()

        Dim itemCorpusFontStyleTitre1 As New CorpusFontStyleItem With {.strTextStyleName = "Titre 1", .fontTextStyle = CorpusFontStyleTitre1}
        Dim itemCorpusFontStyleTitre2 As New CorpusFontStyleItem With {.strTextStyleName = "Titre 2", .fontTextStyle = CorpusFontStyleTitre2}
        Dim itemCorpusFontStyleTitre3 As New CorpusFontStyleItem With {.strTextStyleName = "Titre 3", .fontTextStyle = CorpusFontStyleTitre3}
        Dim itemCorpusFontStyleTitre4 As New CorpusFontStyleItem With {.strTextStyleName = "Titre 4", .fontTextStyle = CorpusFontStyleTitre4}
        Dim itemCorpusFontStyleCorps As New CorpusFontStyleItem With {.strTextStyleName = "Corps de Texte", .fontTextStyle = CorpusFontStyleCorpsdeTexte}

        cmbFontStyle.Items.Add(itemCorpusFontStyleTitre1)
        cmbFontStyle.Items.Add(itemCorpusFontStyleTitre2)
        cmbFontStyle.Items.Add(itemCorpusFontStyleTitre3)
        cmbFontStyle.Items.Add(itemCorpusFontStyleTitre4)
        cmbFontStyle.Items.Add(itemCorpusFontStyleCorps)

End Sub
```

Comment: You're not adding handlers until after you've already added the items.  Have you tried reversing the order of those operations?

Comment: Did you mean like this:

```
Private Sub frmCorpusManagement_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
cmbFontStyle.ComboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
        AddHandler cmbFontStyle.ComboBox.DrawItem, AddressOf cmbFontStyle_DrawItem
        AddHandler cmbFontStyle.ComboBox.MeasureItem, AddressOf cmbFontStyle_MeasureItem
LoadcmbFontStyle()
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks right (unfortunately, multiline code doesn't really work in comments).

Comment: Sorry Craig, it doesn't fix my issue. :/ 
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong draw mode.  Change it to this:

```
cmbFontStyle.ComboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable
```

Also, `Select Case e.Index` is an integer, not a string.  It's zero-based, so you aren't measuring the first item.  Change it to:

```
Select Case e.Index
  Case 0
    e.ItemHeight = 50
  Case 1
    e.ItemHeight = 40
```

You should try actually measuring a font height instead of guessing at a number.

Comment: Thanks and again for the free advice! ^^